# Size Property is not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms

Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Size Property is not working properly.

**First:** The size property doesn't match with the size on the code.

**Second:** It doesn't match my screen resolution. Like for example, I've set the size property of the form to be the same as my screen resolution but when I run the program, the form is not in full screen.

**Third:** Size property is not accurate. It's never been exact, like not even close on the given value. For example, if I make a conditional statement which involves the size property, I have to guess its size in order for the condition to work.

Example:
Panel Size Property

[image: Panel Size Property]

And the code:

```
private void menuButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (menuPanel.Width == 216)
        {
            menuPanel.Visible = false;
            menuPanel.Width = 48;
            menuAnimator.ShowSync(menuPanel);
            menuPanel.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            menuPanel.Visible = false;
            menuPanel.Width = 216;
            menuAnimator2.ShowSync(menuPanel);
            menuPanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

So, technically my Visual Studio Size Property is broken.
I did try to fix this with Visual Studio Repair option but the problem still remains.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: The values that you are setting in the code will be enforced only at run time not at design time.

Comment: "doesn't work as I like" "isn't working" That's not specific enough for anyone here to help you. You need to clarify exactly what you were expecting to happen. Until you do that, this is very unclear.

Comment: Also, taking screenshots of code is *very* frowned upon. It'd be better if you just copy and pasted it into a code block.

Comment: Forget my first question. The problem is that the size property in my Visual Studio is not working properly. Like, it is not accurate.

Comment: @Kurogami as HPierce said, you won't see the code working while in Editor mode, you have to run the application first

Comment: By the way, you are changing a Panel's width, that won't make the form go Fullscreen. For that, you have to change the Form's properties

Comment: The panel is just an example tho'. By the way, I already fixed it. So thanks anyways. Looking forward to my next problem again. If ever, hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution of my problem.
I've just changed my DPI Scaling to 100%.
[Display Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As9sV.jpg)